# Why using .filter() together with .match() is only returning the first element matching the condition?

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

I have some HTML code where at the most nested level there is some text I'm interested in:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    
    <div class="output_area">
      <pre>WHITE 34</pre>
    </div>
    <div class="output_area">
      <pre>RED 05</pre>
    </div>

    <div class="output_area">
      <pre>WHITE 16</pre>
    </div>
    <div class="output_area">
      <pre>BLACK</pre>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need to do is I need to return the `output_area` elements only when their nested <PRE> element contains a word + a number (for example WHITE 05, and not just BLACK).

So this is what I did:

I made an array from all output_area elements:

```
output_areas = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('output_area'));
```

I filtered the `output_areas` array to only return those `output_area` elements whose nested <PRE> satisfies my condition of a word + a number, using a regexp, like so:

```
output_areas.filter(el => el.textContent.match(/^WHITE \d+$/g));
```

**Now, what happens is this function will only return the first matching result**, so I will get an object of length 1 containing just :

```
<div class="output_area">
      <pre>WHITE 34</pre>
</div>
```

**and the `output_area` element containing <PRE> with "WHITE 16" is not returned.**

As you can see at the end of the regular expression I put a "g" to request a global search and not just stop at the first result.

Not understanding why this did not work, I tried to verify what would happen if I would use  includes() to perform a search:

```
output_areas.filter(el => el.textContent.includes('WHITE')
```

(let's just forget about the numbers now, it's not important)

And what happens? **This will also return only the first `output_area`...**

But why??? What am I doing wrong?
I am not ashamed to say I've been banging my head on this for the last couple of hours... and at this point I just want to understand what is not working.

The only clue I think I got is that if I simplify my search using just a == or !=, for example:

```
output_areas.filter(el => el.textContent != "")) // return all not empty elements
```

I get back all output_area elements and not just the first one!

So I suspect there must be some kind of problem when using together filter() & match(), or filter() & includes(), but with relation to that my google searches did not take me anywhere useful...

So I hope you can help!

Comment: `output_areas.filter(el => el.textContent.includes('WHITE')` returns an array with both elements for me

Comment: Have you tried trimming the white spaces?

Comment: @testing_22 yes, just now, and on the real code, and it didn't fix it...

Comment: And what about replacing the whitespace by \s+ in the regex between WHITE and \d?

Comment: Are you assigning the filtered result to a variable? It RETURNS a new array.

Comment: @PoulBak yes it does return a new array, but it contains only the first element in my case

Comment: @testing_22 tried that too, didn't work...

Comment: How many elements does `output_areas` have before filtering?

Comment: @PoulBak Just ran again this code: `output_areas = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('output_area')); output_areas.length` 
# 221

Comment: Not sure if it matters but I'm in a python jupyter notebook web page.

Comment: @PoulBak It's this page but you need to download it and run it with a Jupyter Notebook Runtime so can serve it to yourself and see the same code I am seeing https://github.com/multimodalart/majesty-diffusion/blob/main/latent.ipynb

Comment: May be that Jupyter Notebook Runtime doesn't run modern javascript, try using a browser.

Comment: @PoulBak no the Jupyter Runtime is not about JavaScript, I mean it takes a Python file and serves interactively over the web. Basically it's a web server that also knows how to intercommunicate with the Python process and capable of rendering interactive web pages based on the status of the Python process. It leverages Javascript to work. And it's actually very modern and continuously updated... So I'm just in a normal browser dealing with the page served by Jupyter... and JS for some reason is giving me a hard tme...

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) here to remove space before and after the text

```
output_areas.filter( el => el.textContent.trim().match( /^WHITE \d+$/g ))
```

```js
const output_areas = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('output_area'));

const result = output_areas.filter(el => el.textContent.trim().match(/^WHITE \d+$/g));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="output_area">
      <pre> WHITE 34 </pre>
    </div>
    <div class="output_area">
      <pre> RED 05 </pre>
    </div>

    <div class="output_area">
      <pre> WHITE 16 </pre>
    </div>
    <div class="output_area">
      <pre> BLACK </pre>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No it's not about that, I just added the space in the example code to make it more clear... but it won't work with or without the space (I'm removing it now to not cause other confusion).

Comment: I just tried on the real code using `trim()` and it didn't fix it...

Comment: @Redoman Can you make your code runnable. where you can reproduce your issue. I'm not fully understand your problem now. You can use `<>` in editor

Comment: yes the code here will probably work, but my real code is not working... that's the problem. It's a Python Jupyter Notebook webpage for an open source project, so I'll probably manage to give you a link, just give me 5 mins.

Comment: It's this page but you need to download it and run it with a Jupyter Notebook Runtime so can serve it to yourself and see the same code I am seeing https://github.com/multimodalart/majesty-diffusion/blob/main/latent.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself as for some reason it then begin to work without any changes from my side... Yes, just one of those typical IT cases we all know... :)

Jokes aside, I think for some reason the webpage (the DOM) got stuck...
Probably the Jupyter Runtime (which was serving the page) had crashed without me noticing, and this caused somehow the kind of inconsistency I was looking at.

Moral of the story: if you see weird behaviour in the interaction with a Python Notebook, always go check the Jupyter Runtime status before getting stupid at trying to fix impossible errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm  not sure what the issue with the Jupyter notebooks is, but generally speaking - based only on the HTML in the question - what I believe you are trying to do can be achieved using xpath instead of css selectors:

```
html = `[your html above]
`
domdoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html")

const areas = domdoc.evaluate('//div[contains(./pre," ")]', domdoc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
for (let i = 0; i < areas.snapshotLength; i++) {
 console.log(areas.snapshotItem(i).outerHTML)  
}
```

The output should be the 3 `div`s meeting the condition.

Comment: I was never using CSS selectors in the first place? You probably got confused by the use of words representing colors in the example, which I did just to put up a basic example...
Also given the relatively simple thing I was trying to achieve what's the advantage in using such a cryptic approach?